# Schematic Pin Swap not able to change Pin Group

Tags: pcb, schematics, altium, pinout

I successfully setup and performed a pin swap on a Gate array in my design. However now I wanted to remove a specific pin from a "pin group" and when I went into the Pin Swapping configuration I was not able to change or alter the pin group assignments for any of the pins. I have a another gate array that I didn't do or configure any pin swapping at all and I can allocate a pin group for it pins?

Can someone maybe help me with this?

Comment: It might help if you let us know (int the question) what software you are using. I guess, its Altium, because that's how you tagged it...

Comment: Sorry - I am using Altium 21.6.4 (Build 81)